# Rmarkdown word template style for code chunks

Tags: r-markdown

When I create a word document through Rmarkdown, I have a reference document which rmarkdown uses for the styles of titles and headers and the regular body text. When I create text from within a code chunk, it defaults to Consolas, size 11, and I want to change this default. I could not find a style from within word such that when I changed it, it had any effect at all on the code chunk font format.

From google searching, it seems there currently is no easy way to change the grey background from code chunks, but surely there's a way to change the font family and font size?